# Add text box in powerpoint for package "R2PPT" in R

Tags: r

I would like to export two histograms to powerpoint within R code as following:

```
library(R2PPT)
myPres<-PPT.Init(method="RDCOMClient")
myPres<-PPT.AddBlankSlide(myPres)
hist(rnorm(100))
myPres<-PPT.AddGraphicstoSlide(myPres,size= c(10, 10, 300, 500))
hist(rnorm(200))
myPres<-PPT.AddGraphicstoSlide(myPres,size= c(310, 10, 300, 300))
```

And i want to add a text box for commentary of my plots as below pictures in ideal. 
 OR 
Is it possible i add the slide for layout Comparison instead of AddTextSlide?

[image]

Thanks for your gentle help.

Comment: I have sold old code on hithub that does this.  Take a look at https://github.com/andrie/braidppt/blob/master/R/ppt.R and search for the function `pptInsertTextbox()`

Comment: @Andrie, indeed i realize there is a PPT.applyTemplate() with code myPres <- PPT.ApplyTemplate(myPres,file="C:/Users/HKGGAIT001/Desktop/Presentation1.pptx") While there is nothing change. No warning and no actions.